# why is my field validation not working for date time value?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, datetime

The date and time is in the form:

```
23/09/2015 09:17 PM
```

and I wrote a simple jquery validator:

```
$('#myform').validate({
                errorElement: 'div',
                rules: {
                    (...),
                    datetimepicker: {
                        required: true,
                        date: true,
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM (am|pm)'
                    },
                    (...)
                },
```

but it doesn't work and constantly tells me that the input value is invalid... How can I fix it?
I'm using twitter-bootstrap, so maybe there is some built in validator?
Thanks

Comment: Should the format not be `dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM AA`? Note - case is important in date format strings and `AA` is the usual date format string for am/pm. E.g. have a look at [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
format: 'dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm a'
```

Note the format is case-sensitive.